How to Allow nil Description in Rails STI Special Model Without Modifying Parent Model Validations?
Premise:

Developing an application using Rails.
There is a Book model.
Derived from Book, there are NormalBook and SpecialBook models for STI.
The Book model has a description field with a presence: true validation.
The Book model already has complex validations, and I prefer not to modify them further.

Requirements:

Creation in the SpecialBook model should only occur under specific conditions (integration via API), where I want to allow saving description as nil, ignoring the presence: true validation at that time.
I want to handle this requirement only in the SpecialBook model without modifying the Book model because Book model already has a lot of validations with conditions and is really messy so I don't want to complicate it.

Attempts:
I have tried these.

Using presence: false in SpecialBook:

presence: false doesn't override presence: true but simply avoids adding the validator, so it has no effect.

class SpecialBook < Book
  validates :description, presence: false
end


Conditional presence: true in SpecialBook:

Book model's validation runs first, preventing conditionally adding validations in SpecialBook.

class SpecialBook < Book
  validates :description, presence: true, if: :from_api?
end


Context-based validation in SpecialBook:

Adding a custom validation context in SpecialBook also proved ineffective due to Book model's validations being executed first.

class SpecialBook < Book
  validate :description_presence_custom, unless: :skip_description_validation?

  def skip_description_validation?
    validation_context == :api
  end

  private

  def description_presence_custom
    errors.add(:description, "can't be blank") if description.blank?
  end
end


Skipping parent validations:

Although possible, skipping validations in this manner doesn't align well with good design practices.

class SpecialBook < Book
  def self.skip_parent_validation
    validations_to_skip = _validate_callbacks.select do |callback|
      callback.filter.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator) &&
      [:description, :other_field].include?(callback.filter.instance_variable_get(:@attributes).first)
    end

    validations_to_skip.each do |callback|
      skip_callback :validate, callback.filter
    end
  end

  skip_parent_validation if -> { created_by_api.present? }

  with_options unless: :created_by_api? do |c|
    c.validates :description, presence: true
  end

  def created_by_api?
    created_by_api.present?
  end
end


Removing callbacks:

While effective, directly removing callbacks isn't recommended for maintainability reasons.

class SpecialBook < Book
  attr_accessor :skip_description_validation

  before_validation :conditionally_skip_description_validation

  private

  def conditionally_skip_description_validation
    if skip_description_validation
      _validate_callbacks.each do |callback|
        if callback.filter.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator) && callback.filter.attributes.include?(:description)
          _validate_callbacks.delete(callback)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

special_book = SpecialBook.new(description: nil, skip_description_validation: true)



Objective:

I'm seeking a method to allow saving description as nil in SpecialBook without modifying the Book model.
A colleague suggested that there must be a way using ActiveRecord or Rails APIs, but I haven't found it yet.
I believe there might be a better approach than skipping validations altogether, but I haven't figured it out.


May be it's better to move your messy conditional validations to separate layer. It's a good practice to keep in the models only simplest validations due to database schema (presence, uniqueness). Simple and fast way is to keep all common logics of the validations in parent model and separate in children

@mechnicov
Thank you for the advice. You are right. I have been wanting to create a class for validation and move validations from the parent model to the new class. But this time, in terms of the business impact, we thought we should focus on the way to let the app to create the SpecialBook by API and not spend much time for the refactoring of the book model.

When an instance of the SpecialBook child class behaves contradictory to an instance of the Book parent class then this is a violation of the Liskov substitution principle, which is one of the SOLID of object-oriented design. Simplified it says:

The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) or substitutability principle requires that an instance of a derived class must behave in such a way that someone who thinks he is dealing with an object of the base class is not surprised by unexpected behavior when it is actually an object of a subtype.

Because a SpecialBook has a contradictory validation requirement to a Book, it would be better to move the validation from the parent class into the child class, like this:
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  # Remove the validation from the parent class
  # validates :description, presence: true
end

class NormalBook < Book
  validates :description, presence: true
end

class SpecialBook < Book
  validates :description, presence: { if: :from_api? }
end

Note that this actually makes the “already [...] complex validations” in the Book model simpler, by moving this specific validation into the subclasses with different behavior for both subclasses, and it is in line with the L of the SOLID principle.

Thank you for the advice and you are 100% right, I do agree with you. The thing I have been pondering is that I don't want to touch the book model this time because it takes a lot of time for refactoring book model so I thought I wanted to do it as another big project. If possible, I wanted to find a solution to achieve the small task to allow the app to create SpecialBook by API.

While I agree with everyone else that refactoring is a better option, much clearer, and more maintainable, you can technically just overwrite the errors method (which surprisingly enough is a Documented means of conditional validation)
def errors
  super.tap do |errors| 
    errors.delete(:description, :blank) if from_api?
  end
end


As early mentioned it's better to keep common logics in parent class and extended logics in children classes. You can separate validation in the models. Though it is possible that in your case, when there is a mess in the parent class, it is worth isolating and maintaining it, not allowing it to spread further :-) Since your validation is based on some column, you can just add condition in parent model
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  validates :description, presence: true, if: -> { !is_a?(SpecialBook) || created_by_api.present? }
end

When complex validations occur, which depend on conditions, it is worth thinking about using separate layer, keep only validations related only to schema features (validations for NOT NULL, UNIQUE constraints, etc.)
